# Get text after second occurrence of a specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I have a column with data like this:

```
firstNameLetter_surname_numericCode
```

For example:

```
m_johnson_1234
```

I need to extract the numeric code. I've tried with SUBSTRING function but I just get:

```
surname_numericCode
```

This is the code I've used:

```
SET number = substring(t2.code, charindex('_', t2.code, 2) + 1, len(t2.code))
```

How can I get just the numeric code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the `CHARINDEX` function twice:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
           code,
           NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', code, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', code), 0) + 1), 0) + 1,
           LEN(code)
       )
FROM (VALUES
    ('a_b_c'),
    ('a_b')
) x(code)
```

Answer (score 2):

Heres a one-liner for you

```
   select right('m_johnson_1234', charindex('_', reverse('m_johnson_1234') + '_') - 1)
```

Comment: SET number = select right('m_johnson_1234', charindex('_', reverse('m_johnson_1234') + '_') - 1)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to look for the first `_` in the reversed string:

```
select col,
       stuff(col, 1, len(col) - charindex('_', reverse(col)) + 1, '') as numericCode
from (values ('firstNameLetter_surname_numericCode')) v(col);
```

If the numeric code is really a number -- and no other numbers start the preceding values -- then you can use `patindex()`:

```
select col,
       stuff(col, 1, patindex('%[_][0-9]%', col), '') as numericCode
from (values ('firstNameLetter_surname_0000')) v(col);
```

Answer (score 1):

The SUBSTR and INSTR functions can be combined to get you the numeric code.

```
SELECT SUBSTR('m_johnson_1234', INSTR('m_johnson_1234', '_', 1, 2)+1) FROM TABLE;
```

For the start_pos argument use INSTR to start at the beginning of the string, and find the index of the second instance of the '_' character.  Then use that to start one position after and read to the end of the string.

If you need the result to be numeric instead of still a string, then wrap the SUBSTR() in a TO_NUMBER() function.

Comment: I believe there is no INSTR function in sql-server. It is CHARINDEX instead. Here is the demo of the solution proposition as well as the proof that instr does not work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f4b52212ed3b45983435dd6ac1e210cd

Comment: You are correct, I did not read that tag.  This solution would work on an oracle SQL example, but not SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, and just because I didn't see `PARSENAME()` mentioned.

**Example**

```
Select parsename(replace(t2.code,'_','.'),1)
 From  YourTable
```